# Exiftool get ImageInfo

Tags: c++, objective-c, exiftool

I'm trying to extract image metadata in my Objective-C project via Exiftool C++ interface. 
Code:

```
const char *fileName = "/Users/bbb/Desktop/photos/thumb1.jpg";
TagInfo *info = _tool->ImageInfo(fileName, NULL, 5);
NSLog(@"%@", info);
```

After some debugging I've found out that `isRunning == 0` and `Command` isn't executed  – return with `-1`

```
int ExifTool::Command(const char *cmd)
{
    int n;
    // check to make sure our exiftool process is still running
    int isRunning = IsRunning();
    if (!isRunning) return -1;
...
```

URL is valid and info here is `NULL`. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out what's wrong.
Changed from this:

```
ExifTool *_tool = new ExifTool();
```

to:

```
ExifTool *_tool = new ExifTool([exifExecPath cStringUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
```

Where `exifExecPath` is exact location of exiftool exec file –  `/usr/local/bin` in my case.